# php fetching mysql table date not outputting numbers

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Hi im having trouble with outputting data from my mysql database the code outputs the user perfectly fine, but wont output the date, time or score.

Php code

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');

$Query="SELECT * from highscores";
$Result=mysql_query( $Query );
$Return="<?xml version=".'"1.0"'." encoding=".'"UTF-8"?>'."\n"."<tables>";

while($table=mysql_fetch_object($Result))
{
 $Return.="<table><user><![CDATA[".$table->user."]]></user><date><![CDATA[".$table->cdate."]]></date><time><![CDATA[".$table->ctime."]]></time><score><![CDATA[".$table->score."]]></score></table>"; 
}
$Return.="</tables>";
mysql_free_result($Result);
echo ($Return);
?>
```

This is what the code outputs

```
<table>
    <user><![CDATA[Jim]]></user>
    <date><![CDATA[0000-00-00]]></date>
    <time><![CDATA[00:00:00]]></time> 
    <score><![CDATA[0]]></score>
</table>
```

There seems to be a problem with outputting numbers i just cant think what it is!

Comment: Check the query in phpMyAdmin just in case, to see if it returns the correct values

Answer (score 0):

That's not a problem with outputting numbers, it's a problem with how you inserted it into the database to begin with. If you insert an invalid date/time, mysql will "handily" convert it to 0000-00-00 and 00:00:00 values instead.

Comment: Sorry for such a stupid question and cheers, Moderator can delete this!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're formatting date properly when putting it into the database. I always use this (Note that I only just added the 's-I-G' bit so that it would work with time too, so I may be incorrect in how SQL formats DateTime. If so pop a comment and I'll double check.)

```
date('Y-m-d s:I:G', strtotime($dateToFormat));
```